# Development android app with Eclipse issue

Tags: android, eclipse

I'm beginner in Android development.

Now i want to install an .apk files with specific directory in emulator device,and i don't know how to configure it in eclipse,can anyone help me ?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you mean about setting the setting the directory.

[android eclipse ADT](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/projects/projects-eclipse.html)

This link should help you set up the project if you already havent.

Just clicking the arrow (run button) in eclipse if everything is set up should install and run your app on the emulator

you'll also need to set up a virtual device too if you dont have one configured already:
[Virtual device](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/devices/managing-avds.html)